# Are these two sources the same Scene Builder?

Tags: java, oracle, javafx, scenebuilder

**Oracle**: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html
**gluonhq**: http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

What's the difference? So the one from oracle is the older version and the latter is the more updated version? Am I correct?

It's the same application right?

Comment: Oracle no longer develops SceneBuilder; Gluon "took over" and now develops SceneBuilder...

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Downloaded the new one.